# "Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider" error is showing when application moved to server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql

I had write an api in WebApi, that was working in local fine, but when i moved it to server then it is showing the following error,

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Spatial types
>   and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found.
>   ","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":" at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlTypesAssemblyLoader.GetSqlTypesAssembly()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlSpatialDataReader.<.cctor>b__0()\r\n
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous
>   location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value()\r\n at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlSpatialDataReader.GetGeography(Int32
>   ordinal)\r\n at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader
>   reader, Int32 ordinal)\r\n at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetSpatialColumnValueWithErrorHandling[TColumn](Int32
>   ordinal, PrimitiveTypeKind spatialTypeKind)\r\n at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )\r\n at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper)\r\n at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection)\r\n at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n at
>   Portal.Repository.ApplicationRepository.d__0.MoveNext() in
>   C:\agent\_work\31\s\Portal\Repository\ApplicationRepository.cs:line
>   17\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n at
>   Portal.Controllers.AppController.d__0.MoveNext() in
>   C:\\agent\\_work\\31\\s\\Portal\\Controllers\\AppController.cs:line
>   21\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

How can i rectify this ? please help me..

Comment: By adding some SQL Server Related dll's it works fine in server.  refer this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adonet/2013/12/09/microsoft-sqlserver-types-nuget-package-spatial-on-azure/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/ if the assembly isn't on the server you will have to make it available yourself.

Comment: actually it is not there in local also..i do not understand why it is asking for Microsoft.SqlServer.Types in Server. I had install that in local and checked-in, but the related dlls are not generating in server

Comment: in TFS, getting errors like Could not copy the file "C:\agent\_work\12\s\Application\SqlServerTypes\x86\msvcr120.dll" because it was not found.        Could not copy the file "C:\agent\_work\31\s\Application\SqlServerTypes\x86\SqlServerSpatial140.dll" because it was not found.

Comment: @chaitanyak, I am getting the same, did you ever resolve this?